# iOS shadow is blocked by siblings child views

Tags: ios

I have a problem where my view's shadow is blocked by the siblings child view.

This is how my view hierarchy looks:

```
ViewController View
    NavigationView with shadow
       TabBar
    ContainerView
       ViewController view
          ScrollBar
             ContentView
                Item view's that block the shadow
```

My view looks like this:

[image]

The background color of the ContainerView is custom gray and the background color of the ContentView is clear color. If I don't set the background color of the ContentView to clear, the shadow doesn't appear at all.

So the shadow is still visible on the content view that is scrolling. But whenever I scroll so that a child item of the content view is behind the tab bar, the shadow completely disappears.

I have tried adding 4 NavigationViews into each other and then adding the TabBar into the last view so that my hierarchy looks like:

```
ViewController View
    NavigationView with shadow
       NavigationView with shadow 1
          NavigationView with shadow 2 
              NavigationView with shadow 3
                  NavigationView with shadow 4
                     TabBar
    ContainerView
       ViewController view
          ScrollBar
             ContentView
                Item view's that block the shadow
```

But that didn't help.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Is you `NavigationView` and `TabBar` are custom views or you are using `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar` ?

Comment: You can try 2 ways : 1. Change hierarchy, Add `TabBar` first and then add `NavigationView`. 2. Keep space between `NavigationView` and `TabBar` as exactly and 2-3 more pixels as many pixels you are creating shadow radius of `NavigationView`.

Comment: I have tried that. It ends up looking weird when I scroll. I need my items to scroll all the way to the bottom of the UITabarBar

NavigationView is UIVIew. TabBar is UITabBar

Comment: So you mean that your scroller is seeing behind tabbar and seeing from that space we keep between navigation and tabbar ?

Comment: What is the frame of your scrollview, I mean y origin ?

Comment: But I want to be able to see the shadow above the cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are saying that your `Tabbar`'s shadow is hide when you are scrolling. And Your card would hide that shadow. And when you scroll, this happens : 
[image: Hidden Shadow]

```
ViewController View
    NavigationView with shadow
       TabBar
    ContainerView
       ViewController view
          ScrollBar
             ContentView
                Item view's that block the shadow
```

Change this hierarchy only in story board to :

```
ViewController View

  |ContainerView
  |   ViewController view
  |      ScrollBar
  |         ContentView
  |            Item view's that block the shadow
  |
  |NavigationView with shadow
      TabBar
```

And assume that : `Tabbar` is inside `NavigationView(UIView)`. `NavigationView(UIView)` has shadow. Bottom of navigation there is `ContainerView(UIView)`.

So when you scroll your page :

[image: Tabbar with shadow]

And this would be your hierarchy :

[image: Top View]

Comment: Brilliant! Awesome! Thanks. I didn't have it in storyboard but I used bringSubviewToFront on my navigation view and it worked. And you copied my view almost exactly. Cool!